# How to count numbers in string

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a string that contains numbers like this: 2243. What I need to do is get a total of these numbers. So using that example the numbers in the string would be converted to integers and I'd be able to do this: 2+2+4+3 = 11.

Not having coded in quite a while I find myself a bit stumped on this (probably) quite easy task.

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that :

```
var number:String = "2243";   // Represents your original string number
var result:int = 0;

for (var i:int = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
   result += parseInt(number.charAt(i), 10);
}

// result var will now contain your sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all the individual numbers won't reach more than 9?

```
private var number:String = "2243";
private var result:int = 0;

public function method1(event):void{
    for each (var num:String in number.split("")){
         result += parseInt(num);
    }
}

public function method2(event):void{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < number.length; i++){
        result += parseInt(number.charAt(i),10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, actually they won't reach more than 5. Thank you, that worked nicely!

Comment: @user429333 Please do accept an answer if your question has been answered.